# How to subscribe with Exact Online Webhooks

Tags: php, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I can able to  subscribe webhook using exact online API,i am not able to get response to CallbackURL from webhook notification.

I subscribed using below request:

```
$subscription = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\WebhookSubscription($connection);
$subscription->deleteSubscriptions();
$subscription->CallbackURL = $callback;
$subscription->Topic = $topic;
$subscription->save();
```

Please give me  suggestion to get webhook notification through exact online php API.

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: I subscribed using below request:
$subscription = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\WebhookSubscription($connection);
   $subscription->deleteSubscriptions();
   $subscription->CallbackURL = $callback;
   $subscription->Topic = $topic;
   $subscription->save();

Comment: i want  store webhook notification response at CallbackURL

Comment: Did you read the manual on developers.exactonline.com? You should set it up with a receiver with certificate and correct domain name.

Comment: Yes i gave correct domain name.I followed This https://github.com/exactonline/exactonline-api-php-client SDK link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successfully registering of webhook.

I found the solution how to handle request in CallbackURL.

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

you will get json response.

follow below example you can able to validate your webhook response.

```
$requestContent= file_get_contents('php://input');  // (this is json response)
$webhookSecret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //your webhook Secret key

$returnvalue=authenticate($requestContent,$webhookSecret); // this will get either true/false
function authenticate($requestContent, $webhookSecret)
    {
        $matches = [];
        $matched = preg_match('/^{"Content":(.*),"HashCode":"(.*)"}$/', $requestContent, $matches);

        if ($matched === 1 && isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[2])) {
            return $matches[2] === strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $matches[1], $webhookSecret));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[image]